# Seeking a new, more natural definition of the cartesian product of sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

In "standard" set theory usually we have the definition $(a,b) := \{ \{ a \}
, \{a,b\}\}$, see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) for other similar ones. Then if we set for two sets $A,B$
$$
 A\times B := \{ (a,b) : a \in A, b \in B \}
$$
we have $A \times (B \times C) \ne (A \times B) \times C$, just that they are in bijective correspondence (hence isomorphic as sets). If we further define
$$
 A^0 := \{\emptyset\}, \quad A^1 := A
$$
and $A^{n+1} := A^n \times A$. Again, with this definition we have $A^0 \times B \ne B$, just isomorphism). But for isomorphism any singleton set would work, so for example we could equally well define $A^0 := \{ A \}$, or $A^0 := \{ 1 \}$. So what makes the emptyset special here?

One definition that seems to work better might be the definition as functions as seen on [wikipedia:infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products). But for finite index sets $I$ the above one is usually presented. But still with the second definition, what is
$$
 \prod_{i \in I} X_i \times \prod_{j\in J} X_j?
$$
Guess it should be
$$
 \prod_{i \in I} X_i \times \prod_{j\in J} X_j
  = \{ f : \{1,2\} \to \prod_{i\in I} X_i \cup \prod_{j \in J} X_j \mid
      f(1) \in \prod_{i \in I} X_i, f(2) \in \prod_{j \in J} X_j \}
$$
But with this definition again we have $(A\times B) \times C \ne A \times (B \times C)$, as in $(A \times B) \times C$ we have functions $f : \{1,2\} \to (A\times B) \cup C$ and in $A \times (B \times C)$ functions $f : \{1,2\} \to A \cup (B \times C)$. But at least the definition $A^0 = \{ f : \emptyset \to \emptyset \} = \{\emptyset\}$ is natural.

> So I do not like all the above constructions. Is there a construction of the cartesian product which gives
>
> i) associativity,
>
> ii) $A^0 \times A^n = A^n$
>
> iii) and a natural choice for $A^0$?

The only one that comes to my mind might be to define equality just up to isomorphism (i.e. define the cartesian product modulo the notion of bijectivity), so then in essence we just compute with representations all the time (which by the way would raise many question about well-definiteness in most mathematics books where this is taken for granted, for example in multivariable calculus where $\mathbb R^n$ is interpreted as $n$-tuples and all the above is assumed without questioning it; which by the way is one of my motiviations to seek an alternative construction). But is there any more direct construction which does not suffer from the above drawbacks?

**EDIT**: Changed $(a,b) := \{a,\{a,b\}\}$ to $(a,b) := \{\{a,\}, \{a,b\}\}$; the former might be problematic due to the comments by Brian M. Scott.

**EDIT 2:** changes "$A^{n+1} := A^n \times A$ (still this is problematic as we do not have associativity).", see the comments.

Comment: I don’t know whether that’s a typo or a real error, but the now-standard definition of the ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ is $\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\}$, not $\big\{a,\{a,b\}\big\}$. Also, there is nothing problematic about defining $A^{n+1}$ to be $A^n\times A$: associativity is irrelevant.

Comment: On wikipedia they mentioned $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ as the short variant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Variants But if you say this is less standard I change it.

Comment: It’s not standard, and from a set-theoretic point of view it’s unsatisfactory, since it doesn’t work properly in the absence of regularity.

Comment: What you mean by regularity? And saying associativity is irrelevant seems to me like talking away the drawbacks of the definition, of course it might be obvious that it doesn't matter, but the definition as such does not imply it.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). On another point, the definition of Cartesian product as a set of functions requires that one already have defined functions, and for that one needs ordered pairs. Thus, the definition for arbitrary products already depends on the definition of $X\times Y$.

Comment: Yes, of course. But maybe there might be an axiomatisation which presumes functions as primitive (other than ZFC), but still is this the only possible definition and then talking away the mentioned points of non-associativity etc?

Comment: I expect that there are other approaches, but in all honesty I consider it a non-problem. \\ When I said that associativity is irrelevant, I was responding specifically to your assertion that defining $A^{n+1}$ to be $A^n\times A$ is problematic ‘as we do not have associativity’): to me that language says that there’s a problem in actual *making* that definition when we don’t have associativity, and of course there is not, since the definition still makes sense. Apparently what you actually meant was that you don’t like some of the properties of the objects resulting from this definition, ...

Comment: ... but that doesn’t mean that the definition itself is problematic. It doesn’t even mean that the thing defined is problematic: it just means that it doesn’t behave in what you consider the ideal fashion. In ordinary mathematical usage we can and do safely and routinely ignore the technicalities (‘by abuse of notation’), and in a set-theoretic context they’re generally at worst a minor nuisance.

Comment: If you want a language where isomorphic things are *actually* equal and not by an "abuse of notation", you could look at [homotopy type theory](http://homotopytypetheory.org/).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I took this sentence away.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks for the hint, seems to be an entire new theory for me.

Comment: It may not be what you are looking for, but the category-theoretic definition of product might suit you.  The product $A\times(B\times C)$ is not the same object as $(A\times B)\times C$, but there is a  unique isomorphism between the two objects, and so they are category-theoretically the same. Similarly the choice of $A^0$ is not unique, but there is a unique isomorphism between any two choices. And again, there is a unique isomorphism between $A\times B$ and $B\times A$, which you could have asked for but didn't. The “limit” operation generalizes binary products to arbitrary products.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, that does not seem to be a "construction", but merely a different (but interesting!) point of view.

Comment: Suppose you had a better $n$-ary product that you liked. Then the binary product of something with an $n$-fold would have to know there are $n$-factors (in order to associate correctly) and so could not distinguish between a single set that happened to have the structure of an $n$-ary product and an actual product. That would be a bigger problem in my eyes, and it's unavoidable in set theory.

Comment: @MarkS. I do not understand, what you mean by "a product has to associate correctly"?

Comment: @Stefan, I meant "in order for the associativity property (or similar) to hold true". For example, it seems like you might want $\times_2 (\times_3 (A,B,C),D)=\times_4 (A,B,C,D) $ But you can't get that kind of result in general without $\times_2$ detecting a $\times_3$ and changing appropriately.

Comment: Stefan you may be interested in the comments I just left under Carl's answer.

Comment: @MarkS Yes, I see. If you have such a definition that "flattens" everything then it would be impossible to built a real $2$-tupel out of two $n$- and $m$-tupels without becoming it a $n+m$-tupel, except by possibly introducing two $2$-tupel operations, a pure one and one that "flattens" everything, but that would not be beautiful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category), you'll notice that we don't require associativity "on the nose," just up to (natural) isomorphism. This suggests that its probably too much to ask for the Cartesian product of sets to be associative up to equality.

But anyway, here's the next best thing: lets assume that for each natural number $n$, we have a corresponding $n$-ary Cartesian product operation $\times_n$. For example, we interpret $A \times B \times C$ as beautified notation for $\times_3(A,B,C),$ which is thought of as the set of all ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$. Now, we still don't have associativity "on-the-nose." But we do have a more symmetrical way of looking at everything; namely, there's a "flattening map"

$$A \times (B \times C) \rightarrow A \times B \times C$$ given by $$(a,(b,c))\mapsto (a,b,c)$$

and another such map

$$(A \times B) \times C \rightarrow A \times B \times C$$ given by $$((a,b),c)\mapsto (a,b,c)$$

In my estimation, this is probably the best that can be done.

The same comments to apply to any category with finite products.

**Edit.** Here's something you may find useful nonetheless. Perhaps you want $((a,b),c)$ to literally equal $(a,(b,c))$. This *can* be done. Let $A$ denote the set from which $a,b$ and $c$ come from. The trick is to work in the [monoid freely generated by $A$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) We interpret $(a,b)$ not as an ordered pair construction, but rather, as the monoid operation. Then $((a,b),c)$ literally equals $(a,(b,c))$.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense from the intended meaning of the Cartesian product "$\times{}$" for it to be associative up to equality. $A \times B$ is intended to be all the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  Unless $C = B \times C$, this interpretation would suggest that $A \times (B \times C) \not = (A \times B) \times C$.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I agree. I added something about free monoids, though, which might be closer to what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @CarlMummert What you mean by "unless $C = B \times C$"? If this holds we have $A \times (B\times C) = A \times C$ and $(A\times B) \times C = (A\times B) \times (B \times C)$, so they are still different?

Comment: @Stefan: I just meant that the second coordinates of $A \times (B \times C)$ are elements of $B \times C$ and the second coordinates of $(A \times B) \times C$ are elements of $C$, so usually the collection of second elements cannot be the same.   But somehow if $A = B = C = A \times B = B \times C$ then I think things would be equal (for example if $A = B = C = \emptyset$ this might happen)

Answer (score 3):

The other, "direct" construction is to define $A^n$ to be the set of all functions from $n = \{0,\ldots, n-1\}$ to $A$. This is not an inductive construction; $A^5$ is not defined from $A$ and $A^4$; $A^5$ is defined only from $5$ and $A$.

Of course, the formal definition of "function" may already require a notion of "ordered pair", and the set of "ordered pairs" in that formal sense will usually not be the same as the set of functions from $2$ to $A$.  The formal definition of an "ordered pair" is likely to be something like the definition in the question above.

But, if we like, we can use a definition of ordered pairs *only for the purposes of defining functions*, and use the definition $A^n$ from above to define "Cartesian products" only in terms of functions.

In this direct construction, if $I$ and $J$ are disjoint, then
$$
\left (\prod_{i \in I} A_i \right ) \times \left (\prod_{j \in J} A_j \right )$$
would be defined as 
$$
\prod_{k \in I \cup J} A_k,
$$
that is, the set of functions $f$ with domain $I \cup J$ and so that $f(k) \in A_k$ for $k \in I \cup J$. If $I$ and $J$ are not disjoint, we need to make them disjoint first.

In the "direct" construction $A^0$ is again $\emptyset$, and $A^0 \times A^n$ is equal to $A^n$, because it is
$$
\prod_{i \in \emptyset} A \times \prod_{i \in n} A = \prod_{i \in \emptyset \cup n} A = \prod_{i \in n} A.
$$

Comment: Its probably worth adding that, for me, $(a,b,c)$ *is* a function. In particular: $$(a,b,c)(0) = a, \qquad (a,b,c)(1) = b, \qquad (a,b,c)(2)=c$$ I actually use this notation in "ordinary" mathematics not infrequently.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's just a different function than $(a,(b,c))$ and than $((a,b),c)$.

Comment: Yep, completely agree. $$(a,(b,c))(0) = a, \qquad (a,(b,c))(1) = (b,c)$$

Comment: Here are still some technicalities involved, when you say "we need to make them disjoint first" you are actually altering your original definition as not just considering functions $f : \{0,\ldots,n-1\} \to A$ but extending the domain to functions $f : X \to A$ with $|X| = n$, otherwise in general you could not make the index sets disjoint.

Comment: @Stefan: yes, exactly. I thought this was implicit in the notation $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ that the OP had already used, so I didn't emphasize it.

Comment: So $A^n$ is a special case of $\prod_{i \in i} A_i$ where $I = n$ and each $A_i$ is $A$.

Comment: Here's a cool application if the viewpoint that pairs are functions with domain $\{0,1\}$. We can do away with hybrid function notation. For instance, instead of writing: $$n! = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n=0 \\
      n \cdot (n-1)! & \mbox{otherwise}
   \end{cases},$$ we can write: $$n! = (n(n-1)!, 1)(n=0)$$ We can beautify this by writing our tuples in column form: $$n! = \begin{bmatrix}n(n-1)!\\ 1\end{bmatrix}(n=0)$$

Comment: It would probably be a little clearer to use $\{,\}$ brackets for that last expression, but I'm not quite sure how to put those around a matrix.

Comment: Also, if the identification of $0$ with "FALSE" and $1$ with "TRUE" isn't desired, we can use the Iverson bracket: $$n! = \begin{bmatrix}n(n-1)!\\ 1\end{bmatrix}([n=0])$$

Comment: @goblin Nice formal rewriting of common notation :)