# Properties of the Cartesian product of indexed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the indexed sets $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, one usually defines their Cartesian product as:
$$\prod_{i\in I} X_i =_\text{def}\;
\left\{ f: f\in  \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}  X_i\right)^I \wedge\; \forall i \in I\; f(i)\in X_i\right\}
\label{cart1}\tag{1}$$

For $I=\{1,2\}$, it seems natural to set:
$$
X_1\times X_2 =_\text{def}\; \prod_{i\in \{1,2\}} X_i
$$

Then one expects, for $I=\{1\ldots n\}$:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i  = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\right) \times X_n
\label{cart2}\tag{2}$$

I am unable to derive \ref{cart2}. In fact, the generic element of 
$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{3} X_i  
$
is:

$$
\{(1, f(1)), (2, f(2)), (3, f(3))\}, \text{ where $f$ is a function in }
\left(\bigcup_{i\in \{1,2,3\}}  X_i\right)^{\{1,2,3\}}\;;
$$

while the generic element of: 
$$
\left(\prod_{i=1}^{2} X_i\right) \times X_3
$$
is:

$$
\{(1, f(1)), (2, f(2))\}, \text{ where $f$ is a function in }
\left( \left(\prod_{i=1}^{2} X_i\right) \cup   X_3\right)^{\{1,2\}}\;.
$$

So:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{3} X_i  \neq \left(\prod_{i=1}^{2} X_i\right) \times X_3
\label{cart3}\tag{3}
$$

If that is correct, it extends to the Cartesian power:
$$
X^{n+1} =
X^{n} \times X
$$

If \ref{cart3} is wrong, please, tell me how to prove the equality.
If \ref{cart3} is correct, can we properly define \ref{cart1} a Cartesian product, given that the  standard/expected Cartesian product properties are missing?

### UPDATE

The point of my question is:
since the infinite CP is a generalisation of the ordinary CP, for a finite index set:

$$\prod_{i\in  \{1\ldots n\}} X_i = X_1\times\ldots X_n$$

In words: the finite versions of the infinite CP should work like the ordinary finite version. This might happen with a proper definition of $\times$ for the generalised  CP, and apparently not mine above.

In a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1700030/75616), @StefanH, wants a CP construction which observes  the following properties:

i) it is associative;

ii) $A^0 \times A^n = A^n$

iii) gives a natural choice for $A_0$.

Making the generalised $\times$ associative is the opposite of what I am looking for, because the standard finite CP is not associative. As for ii) and iii), there is no $A^0$ in the standard CP and so no standard  behaviour to generalise.

As noted: if the generalised CP (as defined in $\ref{cart1}$) does not share the essential properties enjoyed by the standard CP, then the name 'generalised CP' might be a misnomer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeking a new, more natural definition of the cartesian product of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700030/seeking-a-new-more-natural-definition-of-the-cartesian-product-of-sets)

Comment: @LucaBressan: Please see the UPDATE section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i  = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\right) \times X_n$$
is simply not true in general (the counter example you provided is valid).

What people usually do is to implicitly identify those two sets using the natural bijection $F : \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i \longrightarrow \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\right) \times X_n $ defined as 
$$ F(f) = \left\{(1, f_{\big|\left\{ k \right\}_{k=1}^{n-1}}), (2, f(n))\right\}$$

You have exactly the same problem if you define the cartesian product as set of ordered pairs, namely it's not associative. Furthermore the ordered pairs definition and functional definition are strictly different according to the standard notion of set equality.

However for the most part this is always ignored (by abuse of notation) since those sets being isomoprphic is good enough for most people using them.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. However could you give a definition for $f_{\big|}$? used in 
$$f_{\big|\left\{ k \right\}_{k=1}^{n-1}}$$
It could be something like $(f(1)\ldots f(n-1))$, but I am not sure.

Comment: @antonio Yes this is the restriction of the function (standard notation). It's the same function only defined on the first $n-1$ numbers.  For more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics) .

Comment: To the proposer: I usually type $f|_S$ (with the "absolute-value" symbol not sub-scripted) to mean the restriction of $f $ to the sub-domain $S$, where $S\subset dom(f)$. To a set-theorist a function $is$ its graph so $f|_S=\{(x,f(x)):x\in S\}.$.. I suppose you could modify this to extend it to cases where $S$ is not necessarily a subset of $dom(f)$ but I don't think I've ever seen the need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your definition of $X_1\times X_2$ to mean $\prod_{i\in\{1,2\}} X_i$ is at odds with the usual definition in a standard development of set theory, where
$$ X_1\times X_2 = \{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid x\in X_1, y\in X_2 \} $$
You may now try to fix that up by defining that $\langle x,y\rangle$ actually means the function that maps $1$ to $x$ and $2$ to $y$, such that the two definitions agree.

However, a *function* itself will usually have been defined as a *set of ordered pairs* already, so this gives us, for example
$$ \langle 2,1\rangle = \{ \langle 1,2\rangle, \langle 2,1\rangle \} $$
which is ill-founded.

It's like straightening out a kink in a carpet -- you need to have one (ugly? limited?) concept of ordered pair before you can begin building a (nicer? more general?) theory of indexed products.

The best you can achieve in standard mathematics is to make each you "$=$" into a *natural bijection* between the sets which you'll need to keep track of.

---

There are some active research movements that seek to remedy this, or at least find a somewhat less awkward way it can play out. For example, under my imperfect understanding, the *homotopy type theory* program attempts a move away from strict equality into a weaker concept under which $X_1\times X_2 = \prod_{i\in\{1,2\}}X_i$ is "just as good as any other equality you *should* ever want to care about" because *every* $=$ comes with a semi-invisible bijection attached.

Comment: As regards the usual definition of $A \times B$, in my recent journey in ST I got that no matter how one encodes things, the objects' properties count. For example, for OPs it just counts that $(a,b)=(c,d) \leftrightarrow (a=c \wedge b=d)$. To avoid abuse of notation or chicken-and-egg problems, one could define functions based on binary Cartesian products ($\times$), ->then indexed families, ->then $\prod$, ->then the a new binary CP: $\times_\prod$. However one should find a definition for $\times_\prod$ somehow matching the properties of $\times$.